# Wordpress as framework

Tags: performance, plugins

Working for couple of Months with Wordpress and developing basic plugins I have the impression that wordpress is not able to handle properly requests if more plugins are activated and mainly because that all of theme are reachable inside of the hole framework. Is there a way to setup the plugins in such a way that each plugin should be called when it needs to be called?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: If a plugin does not do that, it is `doing_it_wrong()`. Two options: find another one - help the developer to improve it.

Comment: first of all I do not criticize wordpress I like it but I have performance problems with it!! I'm just talking about couple of experiences what I had with wordpress when I was running more than 10 plugins. Queries getting executed on places where they do not supposed to be executed, using short codes in custom plugins most of the time are producing buffer conflicts etc.

Comment: I think you need to be more discerning in your choice of plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a plugin only when it is needed the plugin author has to identify the pages where the code actually does something.

WordPress offers a surprisingly simple way to do that: the global variable `$pagenow`.
It is set before a plugin is called in `wp-includes/vars.php`.

In a spam block plugin I have written recently I needed my plugin to run on four pages only:

- `wp-comments-post.php` to filter the posted comments
- `wp-admin/plugins.php` to add a link in the plugin row to the settings
- `wp-admin/options-discussion.php` to show two option fields
- `wp-admin/options.php` to save the option fields

So I added a helper method to my plugin controller …

```
/**
 * Check if we need an instance of our class.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public static function start_me()
{
    global $pagenow;

    if ( empty ( $pagenow ) )
        return FALSE;

    self::$page_base = basename( $pagenow, '.php' );
    $active_pages    = array (
        'options',
        'options-discussion',
        'plugins',
        'wp-comments-post'
    );

    if ( ! in_array( self::$page_base, $active_pages ) )
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

… and check that method before I do anything else in my plugin:

```
if ( T5_Spam_Block::start_me() )
    add_action(
        'wp_loaded',
        array ( T5_Spam_Block::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
    );
```

And if my plugin *is* called it does only what is really needed, nothing else:

```
/**
 * Register actions.
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_loaded
 * @return  boolean
 */
public function plugin_setup()
{
    // Register callbacks only when needed.
    if ( 'wp-comments-post' === self::$page_base )
        return add_action(
            'pre_comment_on_post',
            array ( $this, 'check_comment' )
        );

    if ( 'options' === self::$page_base )
        return add_action(
            'admin_init',
            array ( $this, 'register_setting' )
        );

    if ( 'options-discussion' === self::$page_base )
        return add_action(
            'admin_init',
            array ( $this, 'add_settings_field' )
        );

    // Now 'plugins' === self::$page_base
    // Used by add_settings_link() later.
    $this->plugin_base  = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

    return add_filter(
        'plugin_row_meta',
        array ( $this, 'add_settings_link' ),
        10,
        2
    );
}
```

As a framework WordPress offers the tools to specialize each part of the plugin code. But it is up to the authors to use these tools, and many authors fail here.

Comment: thank you for this details, looks good I'm going to try theme

Comment: if you use classes in your plugins (which I would recommend) you can also use lazy class loading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635386/lazy-load-class-in-php